# Изменение значений колонки датафрейма согласно условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм, который содержит колонки со значениями

```
engine_name | type
----------------------
'3.0 AT'    | A
'4.0 AMT'   | A
'1.6 CVT'   | B
'AT'        | C
...
```

Колонка *type* имеет значение *С* только в том случае, если в колонке *engine_name* значение **только** из букв.
Хочу привести колонку *engine_name* к виду

```
'AT'
'AMT'
'CVT'
'AT'
...
```

Т.е убираем все цифры из значений столбца, оставляем только буквы. Хотел сделать *list_comprehension* и приравнять его колонке датафрейма, однако вылезает ошибка из-за того что есть значения только с буквами. В итоге сделал так:

```
engine_names = []
for name in df.engine_name:
    try:
        engine_names.append(name.split(' ')[1])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        engine_names.append(name)
        continue
df.engine_name = engine_names
```

Вопрос: *можно ли это как-то более лаконично оформить без использования try-except,а например с проверкой по другой колонке?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["new"] = df["engine_name"].str.replace(r"^[\d\.]*\s*", "")
```

результат:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  engine_name type  new
0      3.0 AT    A   AT
1     4.0 AMT    A  AMT
2     1.6 CVT    B  CVT
3          AT    C   AT
```